# "Dereference" Array Type to get it's Singular Version

Tags: typescript

How can I take a type like,

```
type A = string[]
```

and get it's singular version, `string`?

Put another way, how can I construct a `ArrayDeref` utility type that takes a generic `Array` and extracts what it is an array *of*.

```
type ASingular = ArrayDeref<A>
// ASingular = string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
type ArrayDeref<T extends unknown[]> = T[number]
```